# Trying to open activity from button press in fragment. Nothing happens

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Tried to open a fragment from a button in a fragment. Wasnt able to get this to work so decided just to make it an activity. Tried doing this but still am not able to open the activity on the button press.

```
public class ZonnepaneelLayout extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zonnepaneel_layout, container, false);
        Button button2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddZonnepaneel.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            });

        getActivity().setTitle("Zonnepaneel");
        return view;
    }
}
```

Activity

```
public class AddZonnepaneel extends AppCompatActivity {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.add_zonnepaneel_layout);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the getContext() instead of the getActivity()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddZonnepaneel.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your variable View can't start with uppercase letter, set it to lowercase :)

Try to use

```
getActivity().startActivity(i);
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sadly this did not fix the problem and i am still not able to open the activity.

Comment: What are you talking about? There's no reference to an upper-case instance of `View` named `View`. There are three Views: root (`view`), button (`button2`), and the callback view (`v` == `button2`), none of which are upper-case